# In Apache Cordova, why are LocalNotifications handled by the default AppDelegate file, but not remote (push) notifications?

Tags: ios, cordova

I've been trying to impliment localNotifications in cordova, and found a bunch of out of date plugins, but nothing totally current. I noticed in the [cordova source](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/blob/master/bin/templates/project/__TESTING__/Classes/AppDelegate.m#L112) that localNotifications are handled, then broadcast to all listening plugins:

```
// repost the localnotification using the default NSNotificationCenter so multiple plugins may respond
- (void)            application:(UIApplication*)application
    didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification*)notification
{
    // re-post ( broadcast )
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:CDVLocalNotification object:notification];
}
```

But there is no similar handling for push notifications. The phongap-build push notifications plugin uses what it calles ["method swizzling" to add an extra method to AppDelegate.m](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin/blob/master/src/ios/AppDelegate%2Bnotification.m#L22)

It seems like the standard AppDelegate should do both or neither, or is there something fundamental about local notifications which means that lots of plugins may want to listen to them?

Are there any examples of how to write a plugin that listens to the notification that cordova posts? The localNotifications plugins I have found all tell you to make modifications to the AppDelegate.m file manually as part of the setup.

Edit: [JIRA bug which added localNotifications to core](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-1977).

Answer (score 0):

I updated [this plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/LocalNotifications) for use with my app, which is based on cordova 2.5.0, but it should work with  all versions update to 2.9

The plugin is one that requires modifications to AppDelegate.m, which I agree is a bit evil, but I needed a working solution and so had be pragmatic about it.

You can download my XCode test project [from here](http://ge.tt/2aPYovl/v/0). It contains the updated plugin code and modified AppDelegate.m, as well as example usage.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have [something that is working](https://github.com/whiteoctober/LocalNotifications), I'm just trying to tidy it to get rid of the need to edit AppDelegate. I'm not sure if I should be following what PushPlugin does, or doing something based on the handling that seems to be partially present.